# How to get Ethereum token holders amount history and analysis daily

Tags: ethereum, etherscan

I wanna to create a chart diagram for analysis token holders amount history, for example:

```
holders amount

  ▲
  │              ┌─────
  │              │
  │              │
  │              │
  │       ┌──────┘
  │       │
  │       │
  │ ┌─────┘
  │ │
  │ │
  └─┴───────────────────►  date
```

X axis is for date, Y axis is for holders amount, above chart is meaning that holders amount is increase over date.

However the problem is that I can't get the holders amount in the past date, The etherscan only provide a real-time holders amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the total amount of token holders in time from the `Transfer()` event logs.

Use the [getPastLogs()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.4.0/web3-eth.html#getpastlogs) web3 function for example to collect the historical event logs.

- `from` the block when the token contract was deployed
- `to` the latest (curent) block or whichever suits your needs
- `address` of the token contract emiting these event logs
- `topics` help you to filter only some events, or only events containing a specific value

  For example in your case, the `Transfer(address,address,uint256)` event results in the value `ddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef` (keccak-256 hash of the event signature) of the `topics[0]` item. So you can chose to filter only logs of this event - and not approvals, and other events.